# How can I add an Upload Image field to a Wagtail?

Tags: django, wagtail

I want to make form from my page for blog, here's some of my code for my blog post

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
```

and this for my image

```
class NewsPageGalleryImage(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(BlogPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='gallery_images')
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+'
        )
```

is it the best way to make front end form for this is by using modelform django and add the image form as inline form, or using form builder for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Django model form.

The Wagtail form builder is more useful in situations where the form is performing some general purpose action such as emailing a user or adding to a CSV file - those actions are not tied to any particular set of form fields, so it's useful to be able to edit the set of fields through the Wagtail admin, without writing any new code. In this case, your form fields have to match the database structure, so there's no value in making them editable through the admin - it just means you end up defining the same thing in two places.